# App crashing when it gets closed because of biometrics

Tags: ios, swift, biometrics, touch-id, face-id

I have followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RMst1BtMTcE) to set up authentication on my app.
It works fine, but when try to terminate the app, I get the following:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Modifications to the
>   layout engine must not be performed from a background thread after it
>   has been accessed from the main thread.'
>       *** First throw call stack:
>       (0x18bf22a48 0x18bc49fa4 0x18c3f8f08 0x18c1fa03c 0x19035664c 0x190357a00 0x18f604c5c 0x18f6004c8 0x18f600734 0x18f600a54
>   0x18f6054dc 0x18f605328 0x18f5e7004 0x18f97b134 0x18f97b838
>   0x18f990f70 0x18f989d7c 0x18f98b790 0x18f98dc6c 0x18f98e168
>   0x18f98dbbc 0x18f98de24 0x100c0f4ec 0x100c01780 0x1017917fc
>   0x101792bd8 0x1017952d4 0x1017a4160 0x1017a4a88 0x18bc3eb48
>   0x18bc41760)
>       libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
>       (lldb)

I do not understand the error.

Here's my code:

```
func authenticateUser() {
    let context = LAContext()
    var error: NSError?

    if context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &error) {
        let reason = "Identify yourself!"

        context.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: reason) { [weak self] success, authError in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if success {
                    self?.loginSuccessfull()
                } else {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Errore", message: "Riprova", preferredStyle: .alert)
                        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
                            self?.authenticateUser()
                            return
                        }))
                        self?.present(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Errore", message: "Il tuo device non è configurato per l'autenticazione", preferredStyle: .alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default))
        self.present(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    if context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &error) {
        let reason = "Identify yourself!"

        context.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: reason) {
            [unowned self] success, authenticationError in

            DispatchQueue.global().async {
                if success {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.loginSuccessfull()
                    }
                } else {
                    let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Authentication failed", message: "Sorry!", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
                    self.present(ac, animated: true)
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Touch ID not available", message: "Your device is not configured for Touch ID.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
        present(ac, animated: true)
    }
}
```

As you can see, I just evaluate the biometrics. Again: this works perfectly during the whole "life" of the application, but the problem comes out when I *terminate* the app. It just crashes and gets me to the home screen.

There are no crash logs into Settings > Privacy...

Comment: The error message is very precise: `Modifications to the layout engine must not be performed from a background thread after it has been accessed from the main thread.` - most likely caused by one of your alert controller presentations that don't run on the main thread.

Comment: @Gereon thank you, I modified the order of the threads and it works properly. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

please use for authentication function its a global function

```
//enum for response handler

enum AuthenticatinsError: String {
    case userEnrolled = "User is not enrolled"
    case passCodeNotSet = "user not set passcode"
    case biometricNotAvelabel = "Biometric authentication not available"
    case faild  = "faild to authenticat"
    case noIssue = ""

}

func authenticationUser(compleation: @escaping (_ status: Bool, _ msgg: AuthenticatinsError) -> Void) {
    context = LAContext()
    //check inside app if biometric on then in UserDefault set true other wise false
    //let isBiometricOn = WUserDefault.getBiometric()
    //if isBiometricOn == false {
    //context.invalidate()
    //}

    // First check if we have the needed hardware support.
    var error: NSError?
    if context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthentication, error: &error) {

        let reason = "Log in to your account"
        context.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthentication, localizedReason: reason ) { success, error in

            if success {
                compleation(true, .noIssue)
            } else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Failed to authenticate")
                compleation(false, .faild )
            }
        }
    } else {
        if let err = error {
            if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
                switch err.code {

                case LAError.Code.biometryNotEnrolled.rawValue:
                    notifyUser("User is not enrolled",
                               err: err.localizedDescription)
                    compleation(false, .userEnrolled)

                case LAError.Code.passcodeNotSet.rawValue:

                    compleation(false, .passCodeNotSet)

                case LAError.Code.biometryNotAvailable.rawValue:
                    notifyUser("Biometric authentication not available",
                               err: err.localizedDescription)
                    compleation(false, .biometricNotAvelabel)
                default:
                     compleation (false, .passCodeNotSet)
                }
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
            }

        }
    }
}
```

user code where you call

```
self.authenticationUser { (statu, msg) in
                if statu == true {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                         self?.loginSuccessfull()
                    }
                } else {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Errore", message: "Riprova", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
                        self?.authenticateUser()
                        return
                    }))
                    self?.present(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
                }

            }
```

Comment: What is `WUserDefault.getBiometric()` ? Xcode gives me an error on that

Comment: I am handling biometric on off button in side app that's resign I created UserDefault to set true or false in side app

Comment: please comment particular code I am edit code please check